# Segmenting video with ffmpeg not producing durations specified with -segment_time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have an .mp4 file that I'm trying to segment into equal duration clips of 5s each, but I cannot exactly achieve this. The input file was encoded to force key frames every 5s as follws:

`ffmpeg -i master.mp4 -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*5) master_2.mp4`

The first command I tried to used to achieve this is as follows, but the output files were all 8.91s in duration:

`ffmpeg -i master_2.mp4 -f segment -segment_time 5 -reset_timestamps 1 -output_%03d.mp4`

After some research, I modified to the following, which produced better results - 4.91s each:

`ffmpeg -i master_2.mp4 -f segment -segment_time 5 -reset_timestamps 1 -break_non_keyframes 1 output_%03d.mp4`

What parameters should be used to achieve 5.0s clips?

The ffprobe of the input file (master_2.mp4) is as follows:

```
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 66.100 / 56. 66.100
  libavcodec     58.126.100 / 58.126.100
  libavformat    58. 68.100 / 58. 68.100
  libavdevice    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavfilter     7.107.100 /  7.107.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'master_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.68.100
  Duration: 00:04:58.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4754 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4617 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : WowzaStreamingEngine
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : WowzaStreamingEngine
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Follows is a snippet of the key frame timings within this file:

```
5.005000
10.010000
15.015000
20.020000
25.025000
30.030000
35.001633
40.006633
45.011633
50.016633
55.021633
60.026633
....
```

Thanks in advance for any help offered!

Comment: I am not ninja enough to help with this, but I use a program called Neav1e by Alkl58 to transcode video from h.264 to av1. It uses ffmpeg to do chunking in order to make the av1 encoding process more parallel. You can see how they do this (including the command structure) between lines 167 and 190 of the Github page: (https://github.com/Alkl58/NotEnoughAV1Encodes/blob/master/NotEnoughAV1Encodes/Video/VideoSplitter.cs) Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much @WordNerd - I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to run a test conversion for you in that program I mentioned in my comment above and then review the log to see if it spit out the ffmpeg commands used to do the equal-length chunking. I've got something which I've edited to more closely align with your nearly-working sample command.

Try this and see what happens:
`ffmpeg.exe -i "master_2.mp4" -reset_timestamps 1 -sc_threshold 0 -g 5 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t, n_forced * 5)" -segment_time 5 -f segment output_%03d.mp4`

Comment: That works great - thank you so much!  The duration is now 5.01s which is I expect is as close as it could ever get. I'll have to try and unwind what those extra parameters do.  Thanks again!!